# Can there be more than one slider using jssor?

Tags: jssor

I have just started using a library called JSSOR (for sliding elements) http://www.jssor.com/ and I'm wondering if there can be more than one element sliding on the same page.

I couldn't get it to work using a javascript library called marquee (not marquee the tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can place multiple jssor sliders on one page.

Note that different slider uses different name. If the name of the first slider is `slider1`, you can name the second slider as `slider2` then.

Btw, you can  search `jssor multiple` on stackoverflow.